# Writing file inside zip using libzip

Tags: android, c++, libzip

I am using libzip android port from [here](https://github.com/julienr/libzip-android). I am able to add a new file in my archive calling `zip_add(_zip, filePath, zip_source_callback)`. it creates an empty file. How can i write data to this empty file?

I know i have to handle it in my `zip_source_callback` method but i don't know exactly what and how.
Any help will be appreciated.

my zip_source_callback looks like this for now:

```
ssize_t  _source_callback(void *state, void *data, size_t len, enum zip_source_cmd cmd)
{
    ssize_t r = 0;
    switch ( cmd )
    {
        case ZIP_SOURCE_OPEN:
        {
            LOGD("ZIP_SOURCE_OPEN");
            break;
        }
        case ZIP_SOURCE_CLOSE:
        {
            LOGD("ZIP_SOURCE_CLOSE");
            break;
        }
        case ZIP_SOURCE_STAT:
        {
            LOGD("ZIP_SOURCE_STAT");
            break;
        }
        case ZIP_SOURCE_ERROR:
        default:
        {
            LOGD("ZIP_SOURCE_ERROR");
            break;
        }
        case ZIP_SOURCE_READ:
        {
            LOGD("ZIP_SOURCE_READ");
            break;
        }
        case ZIP_SOURCE_FREE:
        {
            LOGD("ZIP_SOURCE_FREE");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return r;
}
```

Comment: `zip_add` is deprecated. The functions to use are outlined at https://libzip.org/documentation/libzip.html

Comment: What is the source of the data you want to add? Is it a file on disk, a block of data in memory, or can the data be generated piecemeal via function calls?

Comment: @RyanCu data is generated on run time and is in a vector variable

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `zip_source_callback` if the data you want to add is a contiguous block of memory; you can use `zip_source_buffer` to create the `zip_source_t` you need, which is simpler. There is an example of how to use `zip_source_buffer` at https://libzip.org/documentation/zip_file_add.html

Here I've adapted their example for adding the memory in a `std::vector` called `dataVector`. This code would be placed between the code opening and closing the zip archive.

```
zip_source_t *source;
if ((source=zip_source_buffer(archive, dataVector.data(), dataVector.size(), 0)) == nullptr ||
    zip_file_add(archive, name, source, ZIP_FL_ENC_UTF_8) < 0) {
        zip_source_free(source);
        printf("error adding file: %s\n", zip_strerror(archive));
}
```